# Esconder form através das teclas C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estou fazendo um menu em c# e o mesmo só abre quando o jogo está aberto ou em execução,ou seja, se o jogo estiver rodando mostre o menu, até aí tudo bem ele executa, porém eu queria esconder o menu por exemplo ao apertar F1 no teclado sem usar botão minimizar da janela form, depois mostrar novamente ao apertar a tecla até pq to usando bordernone não tem os botões minimizar e nem fechar. já tentei alguns tutorias na net mais como sou iniciante  fiz a maior bagunça aqui =/. Alguém poderia me ajudar? desde já grato.

Comment: Se esse jogo entra em full screen, vai ficar um pouco difícil contornar, até o próprio "team speak" usa o Overwolf pra conseguir esse feito :/

Comment: Obrigado vicnius mas acabei achando de ultima hora esse tutorial. 1° segue esse tutorial crianda a classe KeyboardHook: https://wphone7.wordpress.com/2008/08/23/easy-way-global-keyboard-hooking-in-net-application/ 2° depois esse: https://wphone7.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/hiding-windows-form-in-c-using-global-keyboard-shortcut/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua tela, você pode usar o evento [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) para capturar o pressionamento de uma tecla. Caso esteja usando Windows Forms, não esqueça de setar a propriedade [`KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) do formulário para True.

```
private void MeuFormulario_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Só não esqueça de [vincular o evento com o método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius por responder, mas acabei achando aos 48 um tutorial , tem que usar hook heyboard.

Comment: Posta a solução aí pra gente, como resposta, assim você pode acabar ajudando mais pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.